# Is it normal for my disk usage to be at 100% nearly all the time for 2 years?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, hybrid-disk

4TB Hybrid disk from [Seagate](http://www.seagate.com/consumer/upgrade/desktop-solid-state-hybrid-drive/).

EDIT: Windows 8.1

Occasionally it goes to 0%. Usually it's at 100%. It's hardly ever anywhere in between.

But the computer is usually very quiet, just a low hum.

And everything has worked pretty well for most of the last year and half, except there have been some slow response times occasionally lately. But not terrible.

Could Task Manager be wrong because the disk is a hybrid?

[image: 100pct disk usage]

[image]
(Meanwhile, my CPU is almost always well below 10%)

RAM has never been much of a problem. The 90% RAM at the moment is because I have 6 of 16 GB allocated to a virtual machine. And Google Chrome eats of most of the rest (memory hog).

Disk Queue Length is hovering around 6 at the moment.

Comment: What are you doing with/on that system? Depending on it, it might be OK. An average response time of 2 seconds usually would be noticeable.

Comment: I usually just have a fair number of Chrome browser windows open (20-50 tabs), and 10-15 excel workbooks open. Sometimes I also have a VirtualBox virtual machine or 2 running, plus my IDE (phpStorm). But it doesn't seem to matter what's open. Always 100% disk usage.
Right now, response time is hitting 6 seconds but for the most part everything feels normal.

Comment: Open Resource Monitor and go into the Disk tab. Let's see what your queue depth is like. I agree with Seth, an average response time on the order of seconds would **absolutely** be noticable in ordinary usage. Though being at almost 90% RAM utilization indicates that your system may be swapping heavily; a screenshot of the memory tab as well from Task Manager would be nice.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling RAM has never been much of a problem. The 90% RAM at the moment is because I have 6 of 16 GB allocated to a virtual machine. And Google Chrome eats of most of the rest (memory hog). I'm adding screenshot, though.

Comment: See if [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3083595/task-manager-might-show-100-disk-utilization-on-windows-10-devices-with-message-signaled-interrupt-msi-mode-enabled) helps.

Comment: @harrymc although your link is for windows 10 rather than 8.1, that looks quite promising. I will try it in about 8 hours when I wake up.

Comment: You'll need tho check the processes. Click on "open ressource monitor" on your screenshot and you'll find the program causing the issue.
Could be the AV software, Windows Indexing (Search Engine) or anything else.

Comment: Check your VMs for services etc that hit the disk a lot, like indexing, windows update etc. turn them off and see if it impacts active time.

Comment: @Yorik VMs are usually Ubuntu or CentOS, but disk issue occurs with or without VMs. Disk issue doesn't seem to depend on what programs are running. I'm going to try harrymc's suggestion when I wake up, since it relates directly to SSDs and Windows disk usage, although my disk is hybrid rather than pure SSD.